# Get same column twice, different value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the following code (you don't need to know much of the query to get my question):

```
if ($stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT p.post_id, p.reply_to, p.parent_id, p.post_path, p.user_id, p.content, p.datetime, p.total_likes, p.total_replies, p.total_reposts, l.like_id, l.user_id, u.username, u.display_name 
        FROM posts p 
        LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id 
        LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id 
        WHERE l.user_id IN 
            (SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE user_id IN 
                (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ? AND following_id != ?)) 
        AND l.user_id != p.user_id AND p.removed != 1 
        ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $id, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($post_id, $reply_to, $parent_id, $post_path, $user_id, $content, $datetime, $total_likes, $total_replies, $total_reposts, $like_id, $like_user_id, $username, $display_name);
}
```

Right now, I have the `l.user_id` value which is the integer value of the user.

How would I add to this query so that I can get the username of `l.user_id` from the `users` table when I'm already querying `u.username` for `p.user_id`?

Thanks!

Comment: Just add the field to your query?  I guess I am not understanding your question.

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm already getting `u.username` for `p.user_id`. I also want to get the username of `l.user_id`. How?

Comment: Just add `l.username` to your query.

Comment: @MikeBrant Got the error `Trying to get property of non-object` on line `if ($stmt->num_rows) {`.

Comment: I don't even see that line of code here???

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias to achieve this, they are meant to be used in such your situation, for example

```
SELECT l.user_name as user, u.username as uname, ....
```

From documentation

**SQL Aliases**

> - SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.
> - Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.

Learn more [**`here`**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: I'm still not sure how this helps my situation.

Comment: @Walter In your case `SELECT l.user_id as LUserID, p.user_id as PUserID` should get the user id as 2 different cols from the 2 tables.

Comment: @walter assigning alias will help you hretrieve different columns from different tables with same name

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if ($stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT p.post_id, p.reply_to, p.parent_id, p.post_path, p.user_id, p.content, p.datetime, p.total_likes, p.total_replies, p.total_reposts, l.like_id, l.user_id, l.username as lusername , u.username, u.display_name 
    FROM posts p
    ....
```

EDIT:

change this

```
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.user_id= u.user_id
```

Comment: Didn't work. What I need to do is use `l.user_id` (this comes from the likes table) and get the username from the users table.